# Non-readable POM(The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I am getting Maven POM loading error for local dependencies added into my java project. The error says -

```
Non-readable POM C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\com\example\Sample\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\Sample-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\pom.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I can confirm that the jar is present at the location & the POM.xml is valid and I also tried "**Maven->Update Project**" but that did not help. When I remove the maven dependency and add it again, the issue disappears but it reappears later again after restarting the eclipse and cleaning up the project. What am I missing?

Comment: Sample-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\pom.xml - Doesnt seem to be correct. What do you want to do ?

Comment: Yeah. I found it strange too. I just added maven dependency. `<dependency>
     <groupId>com.example</groupId>
     <artifactId>Sample</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>` .

Comment: Ignore the eclipse for a moment. Did you try executing/building project directly from command line ?

Comment: Yes it does work fine from command line.